# Iterate through multiple APIs and save them to separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with data from the UK Charity Commission API. I have a list of charity numbers ('charityNum') and I want to use them to make multiple API calls, below is a list of calls and the dataframe names I want to assign them to:

```
calls = ['allcharitydetails',
         'charityaraccounts', 
         'charityareaofoperation', 
         'charityassetsliabilities', 
         'checkprimarygrants', 
         'charityfinancialhistory',
         'charitygoverningdocument',
         'charityoverview',
         'charitypolicyinformation',
         'charityregulatoryreport']

dfNames = ['allDetailsDF',
           'accountsDF',
           'areaDF',
           'assetsDF',
           'grantsDF',
           'financialDF',
           'governingDF',
           'overviewDF',
           'policyDF',
           'regulatoryDF']
```

At the moment, I only have been able to set up the below API call, which does not loop through all the different calls, just the different charity numbers in the list (I have starred out my API key):

```
detailsDF = pd.DataFrame([])
for num in charityNum:
    url = "https://api.charitycommission.gov.uk/register/api/allcharitydetails/{}/0"
    hdr ={
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '******************',
    }
    req = urllib.request.Request(url.format(num), headers=hdr)
    req.get_method = lambda: 'GET'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(string)
    df_temp = pd.json_normalize(data)
    detailsDF = pd.concat([detailsDF, df_temp],ignore_index=True,sort=False)
```

I will be able to copy this code down and make multiple dataframes, but ideally I would use the for loop to cycle through all the different calls for all numbers in the charityNum list and assign them to different dataframes.

Comment: In each charity number, we'll find all the data `('allDetailsDF', 'accountsDF', ..)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altough you can use [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#globals) to dynamically create your dataframes (*based on* `dfNames`), I highly suggest you to do not (*becasue it may be risky*) and, instead, you can bootstrap a dictionnary of dataframes, this way :

```
from collections import defaultdict

dfs = defaultdict(list)

for num in charityNum:
    for call, name in zip(calls, dfNames):
        url = f'https://api.charitycommission.gov.uk/register/api/{call}/{num}/0'
        hdr = {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '******************',
        }
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
        req.get_method = lambda: 'GET'
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
        tmp_df = (pd.json_normalize(json.loads(string))
                      .assign(charity_number=num, call_label=call)) # <-- optional
        dfs[name].append(tmp_df)
        
for name in dfNames:
    dfs[name] = pd.concat(dfs[name], ignore_index=True)
```

For example, to ask for the `"financialDF"` DataFrame, you can use dictionnary *key-indexing*: `dfs["financialDF"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the code into functions that (i) get the data for one call and one charity, (ii) loop over all charities and (iii) loop over all calls.

```
def get_charity_data(call, charity_number):
    url = f"https://api.charitycommission.gov.uk/register/api/{call}/{charity_number}/0"
    hdr ={
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '******************',
    }
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
    req.get_method = lambda: 'GET'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(string)
    return pd.json_normalize(data)

def get_all_charities_data(call, charity_numbers):
    dfs = [get_charity_data(call, number) for number in charity_numbers]
    return pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

def get_all_calls_data(calls, names, charity_numbers):
    return {name: get_all_charities_data(call, charity_numbers)
         for call, name in zip(calls, names)}

result = get_all_calls_data(calls, dfNames, charityNum)  # result will be a dictionary of dataframes
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to answer your question using the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/) package, which provides a user-friendly interface to handling URL requests.

A couple of observations which influenced the code I wrote:

- All the API's you need follow the same pattern, which is why we can leverage a single URL pattern with placeholders
- While all API's return JSON responses, some of them return a result which requires multiple lines in a DataFrame (these are the JSON responses that come as lists), while others only need 1 line (these are the dictionaries)
- Since you did not provide charity numbers in your question, I used some random charities; however, not all API endpoints provide information for all charities. You need to think about how to handle that.
- I agree with @Timeless on the use of a dictionary to store your results

Here's my code - hope it helps!

```
import warnings

import requests    
import pandas as pd

charity_numbers = [******, ******]  # list of all charity numbers for which we want information
api_endpoints = [
    'allcharitydetails',
    'charityaraccounts', 
    'charityareaofoperation', 
    'charityassetsliabilities', 
    'checkprimarygrants', 
    'charityfinancialhistory',
    'charitygoverningdocument',
    'charityoverview',
    'charitypolicyinformation',
    'charityregulatoryreport']

api_header = {
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{YOUR API KEY}',
}


def perform_url_request(api_endpoint, charity_reg_number, headers):
    """Returns information from Charity Commission API.

    Arguments:
        api_endpoint: Name of endpoint that should be called, e.g. checkprimarygrants.
        charity_reg_number: The registration number of the charity.
        headers: API header containing subscription key.

    Returns:
        JSON API response.
    """

    url = f"https://api.charitycommission.gov.uk/register/api/{api_endpoint}/{charity_reg_number}/0"

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json()

    elif r.status_code == 404:
        return warnings.warn(f"Returned {r.status_code} on endpoint `{api_endpoint}` for charity number `{charity_reg_number}`")

    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"No logic implemented for status code {r.status_code}!")


def format_api_response(url_response, charity_number, collected_data):
    """Formats JSON responses in a way that they can be transformed to DataFrame.

    Given that not all API Endpoints return the charity number for which the
    information was obtained in the first place, this function adds the charity
    number to all API responses.

    Arguments:
        url_response: JSON API response, obtained by perform_url_request.
        charity_number: The registration number of the charity.
        collected_data: List containing all API responses which have previously
            been collected and formatted. 

    Returns:
        collected_data containing formatted API response from latest call.
    """
    if url_response:
        if isinstance(url_response, list):
            for item in url_response:
                item['_charity_number'] = charity_number
            collected_data.extend(url_response)

        else:
            url_response['_charity_number'] = charity_number
            collected_data.append(url_response)

    return collected_data

# iterate over every endpoint and charity number to retrieve information
df_dict = {}  # stores dataframes in a dictionary, using endpoint name as key

for api_endpoint in api_endpoints:

    collected_data = list()

    for charity in charity_numbers:

        response = perform_url_request(
            api_endpoint=api_endpoint, 
            charity_reg_number=charity, 
            headers=api_header
        )

        collected_data = format_api_response(
            url_response=response,
            charity_number=charity,
            collected_data=collected_data
        )
    
    endpoint_df = pd.DataFrame(collected_data)
    df_dict[api_endpoint] = endpoint_df
```